# UnboundLocalError at /cart/add_cart/3 cannot access local variable 'cart' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am trying to create a cart if it does not exist using try block but i am getting error that it cannot access local variable cart here is my views.py code

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from store.models import Product
from . models import cart, cartitems



def cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart



def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id) #get the product
    
    try:
        cart = cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request)) #get the cart using cart id
    except cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart =cart.objects.create(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
        cart.save()

    try:
        cart_item = cartitems.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except cart_item.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = cartitems.objects.create(
        product = product,
        quantity = 1,
        cart = cart,

            )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart')

def cart(request):
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html')
```

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering might be due to a naming conflict between the `cart` variable in your `add_cart` function and the cart model imported from your models file. To resolve this issue, you need to choose a different name for the variable.

Here's an updated version of your `add_cart` function with the variable name changed to `cart_model` to avoid the naming conflict:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from store.models import Product
from .models import Cart, CartItems


def cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart


def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)  # get the product

    try:
        cart_model = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=cart_id(request))  # get the cart using cart id
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart_model = Cart.objects.create(cart_id=cart_id(request))
        cart_model.save()

    try:
        cart_item = CartItems.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart_model)
        cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItems.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItems.objects.create(
            product=product,
            quantity=1,
            cart=cart_model,
        )
        cart_item.save()
    
    return redirect('cart')


def cart(request):
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html')
```

Please check if it works tho

Comment: still the same thing its giving me this error 'cannot access local variable 'cart_model' where it is not associated with a value'

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: It is, I’m not a programmer